# Azure MS SQL select takes more than 10 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, optimization, indexing

I have a query performance issue, sometimes the Select query execution takes more than 10 minutes.The table size is 26GB with 8 millions data.
The query is:

```
SELECT X.[PRIMARY], E.[COLUMN_2], E.[COLUMN_3], E.[COLUMN_4], E.[COLUMN_5]...E.[COLUMN_N]
FROM(
SELECT E.[PRIMARY], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_SORT DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM dbo.[TABLE]E WITH(NOLOCK) WHERE COLUMN_WHERE_1 = 11943 AND COLUMN_WHERE_2 = 0) X
JOIN dbo.[TABLE] E WITH(NOLOCK) on E.[PRIMARY] = X.[PRIMARY]
WHERE RowNumber > 150 AND RowNumber <= 200
ORDER BY COLUMN_SORT
```

I have nonclustered INDEX (COLUMN_WHERE_1, COLUMN_WHERE_2) INCLUDE ( COLUMN_SORT).

The execution plan looks like

[image]

Do you have an idea, how the query or the index can be optimized?

Comment: @Ivan Starostin 3 KB per row..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an index is created with key columns that match those in the *ORDER BY* clause in the query( *the nested one in your case* ), the *SORT* operator can be eliminated in the query plan and the query plan is more efficient. So, the following *NONCLUSTERED* index might be created :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ColumnSort  
ON dbo.[TABLE]  
    (COLUMN_SORT DESC, COLUMN_WHERE_1, COLUMN_WHERE_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from this:

```
SELECT E.[PRIMARY], E.[COLUMN_2], E.[COLUMN_3], E.[COLUMN_4], E.[COLUMN_5]...E.[COLUMN_N]
FROM(
    SELECT E.[PRIMARY], E.[COLUMN_2], E.[COLUMN_3], E.[COLUMN_4], E.[COLUMN_5]...E.[COLUMN_N],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COLUMN_SORT DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM dbo.[TABLE]E
    WHERE COLUMN_WHERE_1 = 11943 AND COLUMN_WHERE_2 = 0
) X
WHERE RowNumber > 150 AND RowNumber <= 200
ORDER BY RowNumber
```

- avoid unnecessary self-join
- remove second sort by the same column - you do already have `RowNumber` with the same `ORDER BY` option

Comment: The order by rownumber is a good idea, thanks. But in the inner query I don't want to query the all columns, as this is a big effort on data I/O. This was the reason of the inner join.

Comment: Aren't you selecting those columns after join?